# Designing a Light/Dark Sensor with LDR 555 alternator LED and Motor

Tags: led, motor, circuit-design, detector

I am working on a project which I need to turn on LED alternately as well as motor turned on while it is dark. I managed to create an Electric circuit which can turn on the LEDs together. However Motor is not starting with darkness. Can you please help me with the circuit?
I am using PIC microcontroller software circuit wizard 3.

---

[image: Here is my schematic of what I achieved so far. There are still two issues that need resolving. first is Motor needs to start after detecting darkness with LEDs. And LEDs need to start alternately not together]Here is my schematic of what I achieved so far. There are still two issues that need resolving. first is Motor needs to start after detecting darkness with LEDs. And LEDs need to start alternately not together. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: I notice that you are using a 555 and not a PIC. That is fine, but your original question does not say that. If the LED connected (indirectly) to the transistor emitter is lighting, we must ask, what is the current? and is it enough to drive the motor? Although I don't know the spec of your LED, I would guess you have about 13mA flowing through it. What are the specs for your motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your circuit you are hoping for the current to run through the motor, through Q1, R6 and D3. The problem is that R6 is 470 Ω so the maximum possible current you could get through that leg of the circuit on a 9 V supply would be \$ I = \frac V R = \frac 9 {470} \approx 20\ \text {mA} \$. It's even worse than that when you take into account the voltage drop caused by Q1 and D3. Even 20 mA probably won't be enough to start the motor.

[image]

*Figure 1. Next steps.*

Try rewiring as shown here.

- Run the LEDs directly off the 555 output.
- Connect Q1's emitter to ground. Now you've made an "open-collector" arrangement that can sink the motor current to ground. You will have almost the full battery voltage across the motor and it should easily run up to speed.

Comment: The OP says "LEDs need to start alternately" - to do this, he needs to move R6 and D3 to be in parallel with the motor. Your change has the LEDs in parallel, so they will go on together.

Comment: @PeterBennett. Yes you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! @Sam. The circuit is working perfectly fine now. Is there any way to be the LED's alternate without using a programmable chip? Once again, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Sam edited the answer. I wrote it. See Peter's comment to make the LEDs flash alternately. (Move R6 and D3 in parallel with the motor.)

Comment: @Rakesh - As *Transistor* has kindly explained, I just made a small (but relevant) edit to the helpful answer that *Transistor* wrote. I have upvoted the answer, but as a new user you can't actually make a visible upvote. However as explained in [this article](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) from the [help], you can mark the answer as "accepted" to indicate that it has solved your question, since you have said that your circuit now works.